# how to add firebase_messaging dependency without application failture

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging

I need to get device token for sending notifications. When I add firebase_messaging dependency, my application is not working or opening. It says that "application is unfortunately stopped". A demo application for testing 'notification sending function' is working on my versions. Could anyone help this?

dependencies:
  cloud_firestore:
  google_sign_in:
  firebase_storage:
  fluttertoast:
  shared_preferences:
  image_picker:
  cached_network_image:
  intl:
  firebase_auth: ^0.8.4+5
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2

Comment: What kind of error does logcat display?

Comment: Sergey Solodukhin, 'Please configure Android SDK'